# Online database for android app

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Recently I'm developing an android app and I need to store large amount of data in pre-populated online database. How can i do it? and what is the easiest way to do this? can someone please help?

Comment: You can download it (eg. by HTTP), deploy it within the app. Or maybe you can give more details here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a Web service with some database either MySQL, MongoDB, etc ... and the application using HTTP requests to WebServices and attempt the data.

Here I leave a pretty good example:

- [how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need the following:

1. JSONParser class.
2. Corresponding API.
3. API should reference to database properly
4. Android class should call API URL. (eg. http://example.com/yourapi.php)
5. Android class should send http request using parameters as required by the API.

   For further details and startup, you can always go http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/. The best example to start with, though not that secure. :-)